# How to embed a number in upper 16 bits of 4 byte signed integer?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

What I'm trying to do is to embed a number, possibly with a sign, into the upper 16 bits of a 32 bit integer. What I currently have:

```
#define EMBED_PARM(x,parm) ((typeof(x))((((unsigned int)parm)<<16) | (((unsigned int)x)&0xffffu)))
```

It works for a positive number, e.g.:

```
int value = EMBED_PARM(76,1);
printf("%ld %ld %ld", value, value & 0xffffu, value >> 16);
```

giving:

```
65612 76 1
```

however it fails for a negative embedded number:

```
int value = EMBED_PARM(76,-5);
printf("%ld %ld %ld", value, value & 0xffffu, value >> 16);
```

giving:

```
4294639692 76 4294967291
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You're using `%ld` with `int` parameters. The compiler should be warning you about this. If you're using gcc or clang, compile with options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Answer (score 0):

Your macro is incorrect as the arguments are not properly parentesized, but this does not cause the problem you observe, it is due to `printf` formats: `%ld` expect `long` values and you pass `int` values.

Here is a modified version:

```
#define EMBED_PARM(x,parm) ((typeof(x))(((unsigned int)(parm) << 16) | (((unsigned int)(x) & 0xffffu)))

int value = EMBED_PARM(76, -5);
printf("%d %d %d\n", value, value & 0xffff, value >> 16);
```

Comment: Isn't printf() already promoting all of the values to longs? AFAIR, on 32 bit systems it's doing so promoting to ints. so on an 64 bit system it should be doing the same but for longs?

Comment: `printf()` is a varargs function: `_Bool`, `char` and `short` arguments are promoted to `int`, `float` arguments are promoted to `double`, all other types are passed directly, so the format specifiers must match the actual type provided. `long` are typically the same size as `int` on 32-bit systems, so `%ld` and `%d` have the same effect, but except for legacy systems, `long` are 64-bit on 64-bit systems whereas `int` is still 32-bits (eg: on linux and OS/X). This may or may not cause problems, depending on the ABI details, but using the proper conversion specifiers is highly advisable.